# R.NET、クロージャー型の展開について

Tags: visual-studio, r, vb.net, rdotnet

はじめまして、VisualBasic.net(4.0),Windows7上のアプリケーションからRの操作を試みています。

Rとの接続にはCodePlex上で公開されているR.NET(https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/)を使用しています。（※その後R.NETの公開はhttps://github.com/rdotnet/rdotnetに移っています。）

※まずテストの為以下のようなコードを実行しました。

```
Imports RDotNet
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim engine = REngine.GetInstance()
        Dim obj2 As RDotNet.Closure
        obj2 = engine.Evaluate("cat").AsFunction
    End Sub

End Module
```

これを実行するとRDotNet.Closure型の変数obj2にはRのコンソール上単にcat入力した場合の結果、つまり関数catの情報が格納されているはずだと考えています。

※次に例としてRコンソール上でcatを実行した結果を提示します。

```
> cat
function (..., file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL, 
    append = FALSE) 
{
    if (is.character(file)) 
        if (file == "") 
            file <- stdout()
        else if (substring(file, 1L, 1L) == "|") {
            file <- pipe(substring(file, 2L), "w")
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
        else {
            file <- file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
    .Internal(cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append))
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000a862060>
<environment: namespace:base>
>
```

※そしてサンプルコードの実行時のVisualStudioでClosureのウォッチ式の結果を提示します。

[image: Closureクラスのウォッチ式]

引数の情報つまりFunctionの（）内の部分に関してはClosureクラスのArgumentsプロパティにペア・リストの形で格納されておりFor eachで取り出すことが出来ました。

しかしそれ以降の関数本体の定義部分がClosureクラスのどこに格納されているのかわかりません。

ClosureクラスにはBodyプロパティがありましたが型がバイトコードになっていてよくわかりませんでした。

どなたか関数の本体部分の格納箇所が分かる方、もしくはこういった場合VisualStudio上（2010）で確認方法をご存知の方がおられましたらお助け出来ませんでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `obj2 = engine.Evaluate("functionBody(cat)").AsFunction` とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: Heliac2001様

コメントありがとうございます。
試してみた所エラー（ArgumentException）がAsFunction メソッドで発生しました。

RのコンソールでfunctionBody(cat)を行うとBody部分が出力されるのは確認致しました。

.AsFunction以外であれば実行自体は通るのでAsFunctionメソッドの問題かと思います。

Comment: functionBody(cat)の結果はLanguage Objectなので、代わりに`AsLanguage`で取得することはできます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat`はバイトコンパイルされているので、そもそも`R`で

```
> cat
```

とした時にみえる定義は以下の`PrintLanguageEtc`が出力しているものです。

r-source/print.c at 52c467ea1c4493abe2d1e3483fd0658873a0c629 · wch/r-source
https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/52c467ea1c4493abe2d1e3483fd0658873a0c629/src/main/print.c#L189

`RDotNet`の実装を細かく追ったわけではないのですが、こちらも上記関数と同様に`SEXP`を扱うようなのでおそらく`cat`の関数定義自体は`RDotNet`側では保持していないでしょう。(式の評価は`R`側に投げるでしょうから)

ではどうするかという点ですが2点思いつきました。

#### 1. コンソール出力を文字列に吐かせる

```vb
engine.Evaluate("print(cat)")
```

とした時、コンソール出力に`R`コンソールでの出力結果が表示されるかと思います。そこでコンソールのデフォルト出力を変更します。

```vb
Using sw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim out = Console.Out()
    Console.SetOut(sw)
    engine.Evaluate("print(cat)")
    Dim str = sw.ToString() 'ここに出力が格納されます
    Console.SetOut(out)
End Using
```

#### 2. なんとかR側で文字列を出力させる

```vb
Dim arr = engine.Evaluate("as.character(functionBody(cat))").AsCharacter
```

とすると、`{`以降(引数部分は取得できない)については`arr`に文字列配列(`R`ではベクトル)で格納されます。最終行の`}`が取得できないようで、完璧な解法にはならないかもしれません。

他に良い関数などがあれば私も知りたいです。

Comment: 3100様

回答ありがとうございます。
自分としては単に表示が出来れば問題ないので【１.コンソール出力を文字列に吐かせる】方法で検討していきたいと思います。
フォームアプリケーションで実装する予定でしたので動作確認の為返信が遅れたこと申し訳ございません。

Heliac2001様、3100様、ご示唆頂きありがとうございました。